# Upload files creating dynamic folder based on the user input in asp

Tags: asp-classic

Here is my code that uploads a file to a folder...but I need to upload a file to a folder which might not exist yet. How can i create a folder before uploading the file or is there a parameter in asp that creates a folder before copying the file there if it doesn't exit?..i need to create folder based on the user input...

```vb
<%
Class FileUploader
    Public  Files
    Private mcolFormElem

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set Files = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set mcolFormElem = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        If IsObject(Files) Then
            Files.RemoveAll()
            Set Files = Nothing
        End If
        If IsObject(mcolFormElem) Then
            mcolFormElem.RemoveAll()
            Set mcolFormElem = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Form(sIndex)
        Form = ""
        If mcolFormElem.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Form = mcolFormElem.Item(LCase(sIndex))
    End Property

    Public Default Sub Upload()
        Dim biData, sInputName
        Dim nPosBegin, nPosEnd, nPos, vDataBounds, nDataBoundPos
        Dim nPosFile, nPosBound

        biData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
        nPosBegin = 1
        nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(13)))

        If (nPosEnd-nPosBegin) <= 0 Then Exit Sub

        vDataBounds = MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin)
        nDataBoundPos = InstrB(1, biData, vDataBounds)

        Do Until nDataBoundPos = InstrB(biData, vDataBounds & CByteString("--"))

            nPos = InstrB(nDataBoundPos, biData, CByteString("Content-Disposition"))
            nPos = InstrB(nPos, biData, CByteString("name="))
            nPosBegin = nPos + 6
            nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(34)))
            sInputName = CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
            nPosFile = InstrB(nDataBoundPos, biData, CByteString("filename="))
            nPosBound = InstrB(nPosEnd, biData, vDataBounds)

            If nPosFile <> 0 And  nPosFile < nPosBound Then
                Dim oUploadFile, sFileName
                Set oUploadFile = New UploadedFile

                nPosBegin = nPosFile + 10
                nPosEnd =  InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(34)))
                sFileName = CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
                oUploadFile.FileName = Right(sFileName, Len(sFileName)-InStrRev(sFileName, "\"))

                nPos = InstrB(nPosEnd, biData, CByteString("Content-Type:"))
                nPosBegin = nPos + 14
                nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(13)))

                oUploadFile.ContentType = CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))

                nPosBegin = nPosEnd+4
                nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, vDataBounds) - 2
                oUploadFile.FileData = MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin)

                If oUploadFile.FileSize > 0 Then Files.Add LCase(sInputName), oUploadFile
            Else
                nPos = InstrB(nPos, biData, CByteString(Chr(13)))
                nPosBegin = nPos + 4
                nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, vDataBounds) - 2
                If Not mcolFormElem.Exists(LCase(sInputName)) Then mcolFormElem.Add LCase(sInputName), CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
            End If

            nDataBoundPos = InstrB(nDataBoundPos + LenB(vDataBounds), biData, vDataBounds)
        Loop
    End Sub

    'String to byte string conversion
    Private Function CByteString(sString)
        Dim nIndex
        For nIndex = 1 to Len(sString)
           CByteString = CByteString & ChrB(AscB(Mid(sString,nIndex,1)))
        Next
    End Function

    'Byte string to string conversion
    Private Function CWideString(bsString)
        Dim nIndex
        CWideString =""
        For nIndex = 1 to LenB(bsString)
           CWideString = CWideString & Chr(AscB(MidB(bsString,nIndex,1))) 
        Next
    End Function
End Class

Class UploadedFile
    Public ContentType
    Public FileName
    Public FileData

    Public Property Get FileSize()
        FileSize = LenB(FileData)
    End Property

    Public Sub SaveToDisk(sPath)
        Dim oFS, oFile
        Dim nIndex

        If sPath = "" Or FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Mid(sPath, Len(sPath)) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

        Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not oFS.FolderExists(sPath) Then Exit Sub

        Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sPath & FileName, True)

        For nIndex = 1 to LenB(FileData)
            oFile.Write Chr(AscB(MidB(FileData,nIndex,1)))
        Next



        oFile.Close
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveToDatabase(ByRef oField)
        If LenB(FileData) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        If IsObject(oField) Then
            oField.AppendChunk FileData
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
%>
```

[image: home screen]

[image: upload screen]
can anybody help me?

i need to upload the set of documents corresponding to that proforma number...so i need to create a folder in the name of proforma number which is entered by the user...

Answer (score 1):

just use the filesystemobject to create a directory like so:

```
dim fso : set fso = server.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
dim absolutePath : absolutePath = "d:\path\to\new\directory"
if not fso.FolderExists(absolutePath) then
    fso.createFolder( absolutePath )
end if
set fso = nothing
```

check the [api doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa711216%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for fso

to use that "proforma" number just get it from request.form("name_for_proforma_field")...

as you are using the upload class you have to use

```
fileUploader.Form("name_for_proforma_field")
```

instead of

```
request.form
```

because after using `request.binaryread` you do not have access to the `request.forms` collection...

brief example (not tested):

```
dim upl : set upl = new FileUploader()
upl.upload()
' from now on you have to use upl.Form() instad of request.form

dim folderName : folderName = upl.Form("name_for_proforma_field")
dim fso : set fso = server.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
dim absolutePath : absolutePath = "d:\path\to\new\directory\" & folderName
if not fso.FolderExists(absolutePath) then
    fso.createFolder( absolutePath )
end if
set fso = nothing
```

for further information about the fileupload class have a look [here](http://www.freeaspupload.net/)

Comment: Please check the edit in my question..i am able to create a folder..but i need the folder to be created in the name of proforma number which is entered by the user